# Do unfinished threads hang around after my multi-threaded application fails?

Tags: c#, multithreading

My application starts multiple long-running functions/methods on their own threads.  When one of these threads encounters an error, my program crashes (as expected).  My question, though, is do all the threads spawned by the application stop executing?  or do they hang around somewhere?  If so, do I need to write another application to monitor them so I can kill them?

Thank you!

Comment: Hint:  what exactly is a process, and how does it differ from a thread?

Comment: this picture a bit more complex than they say. you dont crash the process. unhandled exception crashes app domain. and all your managed thread are killed inside that app domain. normally it means the process which hosts that app domain would be killed too.. however if you host it somewhere like asp.net server it might survive... where is jon skeet when academic knowledge needed!? :) i cant say what would happen to native threads in this case... and perhapse there might be other obscure situations....

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When a process finishes all threads contained in that process are terminated. A thread cannot exist outside of a process. Application crash = process termination.

Answer (score 2):

If you are spawning processes from threads the processes you spawn will continue to run after the spawning process ends.  You can kill the process tree in task manager and in code, but by default the spawned processes will keep running if your application ends ungracefully.

I'm assuming this is what you mean when you said

> My application starts multiple long-running processes on their own threads

But maybe I'm misunderstanding what you are meaning to say

Answer (score 1):

If the process which created all threads is killed/aborted, threads are aborted by the OS automatically. In other words: running process = at least one running thread, killed process = all threads terminated.